# The existence of a certain class of triangle using Secant squared

Tags: geometry

Do there exist isosceles triangles such that the length of each side is equal to the square of the secant of the opposite angle ?One example is an equilateral triangle of side length 4, but are there others ?

Comment: Is there some reason for your choice of profile picture?

Comment: Also, as with your other "questions," is this some calculation you have already done up to some large bound?

Comment: It seemed absolutely clear to me. I am truly surprised it was put on hold, aka closed.  I have answered it, so OP got the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let' see whether computation gets out of hand. Let the "top" angle be $\alpha$. The opposite side is then $\sec^2\alpha$. Let the two equal angles be $\beta$. The sides opposite are then $\sec^2\beta$.   Then by the Sine Law, we have
$$\frac{\sec^2\alpha}{\sin \alpha}=\frac{\sec^2\beta}{\sin \beta},$$
which looks better as 
$$\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha=\sin\beta\cos^2\beta.$$
But $\alpha=\pi-2\beta$, and therefore $\sin\alpha=2\sin\beta\cos\beta$.

Do some cancelling, and use the double angle formula for cosine. Letting $x=\cos\beta$ we end up with the equation
$$8x^4-8x^2-x+2=0.$$
This has the expected solution $x=1/2$, giving us the equilateral triangle.

It has another real solution, roughly $x=0.91559$. That gives $\beta\approx 23.71^\circ$. It works. I have no reason to think the angle can be expressed in a pleasant way.

Comment: Thank you for illustrating the existence of this interesting relationship between the only two triangles that exist with this property.